# unable to switch off expose_php in ubuntu 14.04 with nginx and php-fpm

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, php, security, php-fpm

According to phpinfo:

Loaded Configuration File: `/etc/php5/fpm/php.ini`

```
# grep expose_php /etc/php5/fpm  -R
    /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini:expose_php = Off
    /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf:php_flag[expose_php] = off

# curl -I https://MyHost.loc/i.php | head | grep X-Powered-By
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4
```

Can someone confirm this in Ubuntu 14.04?

Any idea how to get rid of X-Powered-By?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems there is a bug in the init script. `restart` didnt restarted the php fpm but didnt reported a problem either. `stop` & `start` worked and lead the no more X-Powered-By.

Answer (score 0):

Add `proxy_hide_header X-Powered-By;` to the corresponding nginx site-enabled file and restart it.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with [bitnami's wordpress image](https://bitnami.com/stack/wordpress) where `php-fpm` is wrapped. It wasn't a bug with `restart` or anything, it was a configuration format problem.

The format for configuration that worked for me: `php_flag[expose_php]=off`

```bash
echo "php_flag[expose_php]=off" >> /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/conf/php-fpm/php-settings.conf
cd /opt/bitnami
./ctlscript.sh restart php-fpm
```